# How to get cookies with guzzle?

Tags: guzzle

The Guzzle site is very weak documentation. I realized that I needed to look at the source code to use all the features of the library, but I still can not fully understand the source code.

How to get cookies with Guzzle from any website? What class to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies representation in guzzle is part of the [PSR-7](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)'s `ServerRequestInterface` [implementation](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/ServerRequest.php), e.g of the `ServerRequest` class. In the class is defined an array property `$cookieParams`. To this variable you can either assign the `$_COOKIE` variable (through the call to the static method `fromGlobals()`) or an array of your choice (inclusive `$_COOKIE`) by calling `withCookieParams()`. To read the content of the `$cookieParams` array you just need to call `getCookieParams()`.

Example using `fromGlobals()` - having the role of a `ServerRequest` factory:

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest;

/**
 * Create a ServerRequest instance, populated with superglobals:
 * $_GET
 * $_POST
 * $_COOKIE
 * $_FILES
 * $_SERVER
 */
$serverRequest = ServerRequest::fromGlobals();

// Display the content of $_COOKIE.
var_dump($serverRequest->getCookieParams());
```

Example of directly creating a `ServerRequest` instance and assigning a cookies array to a copy of it - in order to maintain the immutability of the request object:

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest;

// Directly create a ServerRequest instance.
$serverRequest = new ServerRequest('GET', 'http://localhost/mypath?var=somevar#myfragment', [], NULL, '1.1', $_SERVER);

// Create a clone instance with the specified cookies array.
$serverRequest = $serverRequest->withCookieParams($_COOKIE);

// Display the content of the cookies list.
var_dump($serverRequest->getCookieParams());
```

There is also another implementation, the one of `GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface`, e.g the class `GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar` (see [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/tree/master/src/Cookie)) This is documented on http://docs.guzzlephp.org, at:

- [Quickstart Cookies](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies)
- [Request Options - Cookies](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html?highlight=cookie#cookies)
- [Handlers](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html?highlight=cookie#handlers)

In `CookieJar` class you can assign a `$cookieArray` in constructor and have some methods to handle its values (`getCookieValue()`, `getCookieByName()`, `setCookie()` etc).

Comment: thanks, I figured out the code for the first link "Quickstart Cookies". It turns out I made requests for domains that do not give cookies.

Comment: You are welcome. Great then. Indeed, the `CookieJar` functionality is easy to follow. Good luck.